# how do i use tx.executeSql() javascript function?

Tags: javascript, sql

Sorry, i'm not sure how to use it yet, but this is how i think it's used. Could someone reference me where i can learn more or show me how to correctly code the code below?

Javascript ex1

```
var m1 = "polko";
var L1 = 156;

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO polka(music, length) VALUES (' +m1+ ',' +L1+ ')', [],
    successCallback,
    errorCallback);
```

I already have a sql table made(polka) inside a db.

I've seen people use this, whats the difference? or the more preferred method?
ex2

```
 var input = document.getElementById("save_name").value;
 var time_stamp = december;

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (log, date_time) VALUES (?, ?)', [input, time_stamp]);
```

Comment: http://slides.html5rocks.com/#web-sql-db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var m1 = "polko";
var L1 = 156;

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO polka(music, length) VALUES (' +m1+ ',' +L1+ ')', [],
    successCallback,
    errorCallback);
```

Comment: @user3121403 - `successCallback` will be executed when the transaction is complete. If something wrong happened then `errorCallback` will be executed instead.

Comment: I've edited the original question, thank you so much for your help. However, could you tell me the differences between the two examples? I found it from another stackoverflow question, but i have trouble understanding which is the most preferred method.

Comment: @user3121403 - Both are them are exactly the same according to the [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#introduction). You can choose either one to use. I choose to do this is because you can know the exact location of where the variables are instantly instead of having to look back and forth, searching for `?`.

Comment: @user3121403 - One thing I have to add though is that W3C originally suggested the `[]` argument to help prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but to be honest, it's not that big of a deal if this is not used to store some sensitive data such as user passwords. And just FYI, WebSQL is deprecated anyway and [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) is recommended over it.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 This is an old post, but SQL injection can be serious even if the immediate query is not used for sensitive data.  The entire issue with SQL injection is that it can be used to execute other code which could access other data which might be sensitive.  It is just good practice to *always code safely* since it is not hard to use parameterized queries.  There are other benefits anyway, like automatically adding proper delimiters and character escapes, etc.

Comment: @CPerkins That’s absolutely true. I’ll delete this answer accordingly. Edit: Apparently I can’t delete an accept answer.